# Python thinks my setup.py created package is a module not a python package

Tags: python, package, setuptools, setup.py

I'm using `setup.py` to create a package `foo` and then installing it locally with `pip install .` in a fresh virtual env (python 2.7). In the virtual env's python interpreter I am able to import `foo`, but python seems to think `foo` is more a module than a python package (the package kind with the `__init__.py` file) because when I try to call into `foo`'s substructure, `foo.bar`, it gives me an error about the module not having the `bar` attribute.

For example, I can import `foo` without issue but if I try and call anything off `foo`, it fails with error message:

```
>>> import foo
>>> foo.bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

Here's the folder structure:

```
foo/
    foo/
        __init__.py
        bar.py
setup.py
```

Here's my `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    url='none',
    author='loren',
    name='foo',
    version='1.0.0',
    packages=['foo'],
)
```

Interestingly, I can import bar with `from foo import bar` and not only does that work but it then fixes my above error and further calls to `foo.bar` returning the `bar` module, but that isn't very useful to me.

What do I need to do to get

```
>>> import foo
>>> foo.bar
```

to work properly?

Comment: What are the contents of the `__init__.py` file?

Comment: The `__init__.py` file is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I didn't understand how imports of Python `__init.__.py` packages work. I thought all the underlying submodules of a package (like `bar`) were imported when I imported the top level `foo` package but that is untrue. Python doesn't import submodules on purpose to prevent loading of things I might not use, especially in big packages.

If I wanted to do something like:

```
>>> import foo
>>> foo.bar
```

then all I needed to do was `import bar` in the `__init__.py` file of the `foo` module.

I also learned that all packages are modules, (although not all modules are packages) so that is why my error was complaining about how the module didn't have the attribute.

Comment: You might want to use an explicit relative import `from . import bar` instead of just `import bar` in `__init__.py`, for Python 3 compatibility. (See [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/).)